# Could Les Stroud have used guitar strings for rabbit snares?

Tags: trapping, rabbits

In season 3 episode 1 of Survivorman, [Les Stroud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Stroud) uses a guitar and a can of some consistently shaped chips made from potatoes of an unknown brand <cough>Pringles</cough> to make a trap for mice or squirrels. My question is, since he has made snares for rabbits before, why doesn't he use any of the guitar strings to make snares for rabbits?

[image]

Comment: What’s a quirrel?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh - You made me laugh. :) Thank you.

Comment: and my musical mind went straight to [snares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snare_drum), jumped in here completely ready to mark as off-topic.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum reworded for clarity. :)

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that he wanted to encourage creativity with the available resources.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: There's a close vote because it's opinion based. Possibly, but I'm wondering if there's a specific reason they're not suitable, such as strength or the like.

Comment: Playing his guitar is more important to him than surviving?

Comment: @Drew - good thought - but he pulled the strings off to use it as a trap, then buried it under pine needles and stuff. Maybe it wasn't his best guitar. :)

Comment: Hi Don Branson. I wouldn't presume to edit your title but I have an idea, if you're willing. I think as asked it can only be opinion based. If the real point is in your comment, "wondering if there's a specific reason they're not suitable..." it could be answered well, which Ricketyship did. Would you be willing to change your title to something like "Could Les Stroud have used guitar strings for rabbit snares?" Or, "Can guitar strings be used for rabbit snares?" I'd retract my close vote. Maybe others would too.

Comment: @Sue - great suggestion, kindly offered. Change made.

Comment: @Sue - so nice to run into someone who offers feedback without being a jerk. :)

Comment: @Sue and for the record, editing titles isn't that huge a deal. The author can always reject it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason why a guitar string can't be used for rabbit snares. In fact, I've seen rabbit snares which match the same thickness and quality as the guitar strings (these were illegal poacher traps that we dismantled).

All you need to catch a rabbit is a snare that the rabbit can get into but can't get out of. The bass strings would be much easier to prepare a snare with, while the treble ones might be a bit more difficult to work with to prepare the snare (more slippery and less malleable). Apart from that, no other reason why they couldn't be used.

As to why he doesn't use, it might depend on how good the rabbit population is in that area and how big they are too (guitar string is limited in length after all).

Comment: You're thinking that the bass strings would be easier because of the friction from the wrapping, correct?

Comment: @DonBranson Yep.

Comment: Yep - I have used guitar strings as snares for rabbits. The bass ones are probably better, but they all work, and even a top E string is strong enough (in my experience)